# Diminish org-indent-mode

Tags: org-mode

I have enabled org-indent-mode in all org files as such:

```el
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook 'org-indent-mode)
```

Now I want to diminish the "Ind" minor mode, which seems to be beyond my abilities. I know the diminish package is loading and working properly, as other diminishes work as expected.

I managed to find `(add-hook 'org-mode-hook '(diminish 'org-indent-mode))`, which actually diminishes the mode, but also shows `File mode specification error: (invalid-function (diminish (quote org-indent-mode)))` in messages, which seems like I'm doing something wrong.

A list of other things I've tried that don't work:

```el
(eval-after-load "org" '(diminish 'org-indent-mode))

(diminish 'org-indent-mode)

(add-hook 'org-mode-hook
      (lambda ()
      (diminish 'org-indent-mode))

(defun dim-org-ind-mode ()
    "Hah, this doesn't work either."
    (interactive)
    (diminish 'org-indent-mode))
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook 'dim-org-ind-mode)
```

Using `M-x diminish` works fine with no errors in messages.

Comment: There's a missing closing paren in your first `add-hook`. I'm referring to the list of things you tried.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `eval-after-load` is close to correct. Check out `C-h f org-indent-mode` (after Org is loaded):

> org-indent-mode is an interactive autoloaded compiled Lisp function in `org-indent.el'.

Diminish hacks directly into the variable `minor-mode-alist`, so the call to it must occur after `org-indent.el` has been loaded, not just `org.el`:

```lisp
(with-eval-after-load 'org-indent
  (require 'diminish)
  (diminish 'org-indent-mode))
```

Answer (score 2):

Either of these worked for me:

```
; whacka's answer
(eval-after-load 'org-indent '(diminish 'org-indent-mode))

; fixed Gastove's answer
(add-hook 'org-indent-mode-hook (lambda () (diminish 'org-indent-mode)))
```

Comment: OP mentioned that these snippets don't work for him.

Comment: I don't see where OP mentioned that. Please read more carefully and you will see that there is a difference between my solution and what they tried. Every character counts.

Comment: You're right, I haven't paid enough attention to hook names.

Comment: The first version is included in whacka's answer

Comment: It is indeed. That's where I got mine from. I actually just wanted to comment on Gastove's answer but since I didn't have enough points I figured to post yet another answer with all versions that worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You're very close! `add-hook` expects that you're going to add a *function* to a hook, not the evaluation of an expression. You just need to wrap your call to diminish in a lambda, like this:

```
(add-hook 'org-indent-mode-hook (lambda () (diminish 'org-indent-mode)))
```

Comment: I can't seem to get @gastove's answer to work for some reason, but it pushed me to try something else, which does work:

`(add-hook 'org-mode-hook (lambda ()
                           (org-indent-mode 1)
      (diminish 'org-indent-mode)))`

I think it might be because of a load-order issue, perhaps because org-indent-mode takes time to complete?

Comment: Yes, `org-mode-hook` is the wrong hook to use.  See niko's answer for the more appropriate hook.  The `eval-after-load` method is better, though, so I recommend using that instead of a mode hook.